# how can I install pip in python 3.10

Tags: python

I am having trouble to install pip on new PC.

However, it doesn't work

I have run

$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
$ sudo python get-pip.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/list.py", line 166, in run
    for d in get_environment(options.path).iter_installed_distributions(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/__init__.py", line 85, in get_environment
    return select_backend().Environment.from_paths(paths)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/__init__.py", line 63, in select_backend
    from . import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/pkg_resources.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3252, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3235, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3277, in _initialize_master_working_set
    tuple(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3278, in <genexpr>
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2785, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2284, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2217, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources.extern.packaging.requirements')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pkg_resources.extern.pyparsing import stringStart, stringEnd, originalTextFor, ParseException
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 672, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 632, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py", line 43, in load_module
    __import__(extant)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 943, in <module>
    collections.MutableMapping.register(ParseResults)
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

Comment: And what was the problem with these commands?

Comment: AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'